# is it possible to start/stop "java flames graph" tracing?

Tags: java, linux, profiling

i just started using [java flame graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-06-12/java-flame-graphs.html)  on a **java tomcat server** runnin on a **linux machine** and using its:

```
-agentpath:/usr/local/lightweight-java-profiler-read-only/build-64/liblagent.so
```

however it traces my app since the moment i start it up until stopped.  is it possible to tell it **or any other hack** to allow to start/stop profiling?  note that the `traces.txt` file seems to be empty until i shut the java app down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I forked lightweight-java-profiler and added this feature as well as the ability to dump the current state of the profiler data into a file.  This alleviates the need to shutdown the java process to retrieve the stack traces from the profiler.

https://github.com/scottmf/lightweight-java-profiler